# Functions in Lua

Tags: function, functional-programming, lua

I am starting to learn Lua from Programming in Lua (2nd edition) I didn't understand the following in the book.

```
network = {
          {name ="grauna", IP="210.26.30.34"},
          {name ="araial", IP="210.26.30.23"},
}
```

If we want to sort the table by field name, the author mentions

```
table.sort(network, function (a,b) return (a.name > b.name) end }
```

Whats happening here? What does function (a,b) stand for? Is function a key word or something.

If was playing around with it and created a table order

```
 order={x=1,x=22,x=10} // not sure this is legal
```

and then did

```
 print (table.sort(order,function(a,b) return (a.x > b.x) end))
```

I did not get any output. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) that takes two arguments and returns `true` if the first argument is less than the second argument. [`table.sort()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.sort) runs this function for each of the elements that need sorting and compares each element with the previous element.

Comment: I did understand the logic. My question was why do we do function(a,b) is function a key word?

Comment: @Ankur, yes, it is a keyword. It defines a function. If you use it as `function name()`, it defines a named function. If you use it just as `function()`, it defines an anonymous function. Take a look at [section 2.5.9](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9) from the language manual.

Comment: ok thanks.. Kinda makes sense.. What was wrong with the second part of the question. Why didn't I get any output?

Comment: @Ankur, if you want to define a table of tables, use `order={{x=1},{x=22},{x=10}}`. `order={x=1,x=22,x=10}` will set the `x` key over and over again and you'll end up with a table with a single key, `x`, with the value of `10`.

Answer (score 4):

I think (but I am not sure) that `order={x=1,x=22,x=10}` has the same meaning in *Lua* as `order={x=10}`, a table with *one* key `"x"` associated with the value `10`. Maybe you meant `{{x=1},{x=22},{x=10}}` to make an "array" of 3 components, each having the key `"x"`.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of your question: Lua is very small, and doesn't provide a way to print a table directly. If you use a table as a list or array, you can do this:

```
print(unpack(some_table))
```

`unpack({1, 2, 3})` returns `1, 2, 3`. A very useful function.

Answer (score 2):

`function` in lua is a keyword, similar to `lambda` in Scheme or Common Lisp (& also Python), or `fun` in Ocaml, to introduce anonymous functions with closed variables, i.e. [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Thanks.. makes sense.. So why didn't the second part of the question work?